# Replace Text In All files Within a Directory/Subdirectories In Emacs?

Tags: replace, emacs, directory

I need to replace a certain string in all the files within a directory, which has subdirectories with files also needing to be replaced. Is there a way to accomplish this in Emacs?

Comment: I would say consider using recursive `grep` to find all the locations that need changing, and then use `wgrep` to change them all.  In `wgrep` you can use `M-x replace-string` or use `multiple-cursors`.

Comment: helm-ag works great for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plain emacs:

- Call dired to list files in dir, or call find-dired if you need all subdirectories.
- Mark the files you want. You can mark by regex by typing 【% m】.
- Type Q to call dired-do-query-replace-regexp.
- Type your find regex and replace string. 〔➤see common elisp regex pattern〕
- For each occurrence, type y to replace, n to skip. Type 【Ctrl+g】 to abort the whole operation.
- Type ! to replace all occurrences in current file without asking, N to skip all possible replacement for rest of the current file. (N is emacs 23 only)
- To do the replacement on all files without further asking, type Y. (Emacs 23 only)
- Call ibuffer to list all opened files.
- Type 【* u】 to mark all unsaved files, type S to save all marked files, type D to close them all.

more detail at
http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/find_replace_inter.html

---

Alternatively, I wrote a package just for this. See:
http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp-xah-find-text.html
I arrived it after 5 years trial'n'error of all ways to do this.

It's entirely implemented in emacs lisp, not dependent on shell find/grep/sed etc. So works fine in Windows. Also, it does find/replace in one shot, with colored report. So it's fast and lets you quickly check result just in case. Backup is optionally made.

Comment: Essentially this has to use find utility to list all the matching files, then to replace each occurrence, right? But how to do it in Windows?

Comment: @Michael Wei it's implemented in elisp, so not dependent on shell utils.

Comment: Plain Emacs approach still works with Emacs 30.

Answer (score 6):

I generally do this the way @lawlist suggests.  Here it is step-by-step:

1. Install `wgrep` from Melpa or some other way.  I recommend also
   `wgrep-ag` and `ag` if you use The Silver Searcher.
2. Use `M-x rgrep` (or `M-x ag`) to search the files and get a list of
   lines to potentially change.
3. In the `*grep*` buffer, run `M-x wgrep-change-to-wgrep-mode`.  I
   bind this to `C-x C-q` in `grep-mode-map`.
4. Use `query-replace-regexp` (`C-M-%`), or do any other editing in the
   `*grep*` buffer.
5. Save the `*grep*` buffer with `C-x C-s`.  Use `C-c C-k` to abort.  The changes exist only in the `*grep*` buffer until you save it.  You can re-enable `wgrep` mode any number of times.
6. All of the files in the grep search now have open buffers with
   modifications to them if you saved the `*grep*` buffer.  Do `C-x s`
   to save all of them to disk.

Answer (score 5):

A way to do this interactively is to get a directory listing of all files, mark those you are interested in (may be the whole lot), and then run a query-replace on all of them.

Something like this:

1. Run `find-dired` on your directory, with arguments `-type f` to get files and not directories (you can further filter here by type with something like `-type f -name "*.txt"`). This will get you a dired listing with all files.
2. Mark all files (<kbd>T</kbd> will do by toggling marks), or mark files containing specific text (with <kbd>% g</kbd>).
3. Now run a `query-replace-regexp` on all marked files with <kbd>S-Q</kbd> (uppercase Q).

If the query-replace goes well, you can speed up by typing <kbd>!</kbd> to continue without asking.